# Temporal order in a class

Tags: android, android-intent, toast

I am working on a project and I just can't get rid of this annoying problem: I made a toast message to show AFTER the user enters his name and password (and email if it's a registration process) and also AFTER the app checks data (or store it in the db if it's a registration process, again). Or at least I WANT it this way. But in reality the message shows up as soon as I open the app resulting in a "Benvenuto NULL" message when obviously it should say "Benvenuto [USERNAME]"... I tried using OnComplete but Eclipse says me: "The method onComplete(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method".......

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button reg, log, fb;
EditText username, password, email;
String stringa;
String nome;
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 1000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Boolean f = false;
            EditText txtmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            String mail = txtmail.getText().toString();
            EditText txtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            String pas = txtpass.getText().toString();

            String result = "";
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dati = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mail));
            dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pas));
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://tripleleon.altervista.org/login.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dati));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_REMOTO",
                        "Errore nella connessione HTTP: " + e.toString());
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Connessione non riuscita",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // convert response to string

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_REMOTO",
                        "Errore nella conversione del risultato: "
                                + e.toString());
            }

            // paring data

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    nome = json_data.getString("idutente");
                    Log.i("log_tag",
                            ", nome: " + json_data.getString("idutente")
                                    + ", email: "
                                    + json_data.getString("email")
                                    + ", password: "
                                    + json_data.getString("password")
                                    + ", eta: "
                                    + json_data.getString("age"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Log.e("log_REMOTO", "Errore json: " + e1.toString());
                f = true;
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                Log.e("log_REMOTO", "Errore JSON: " + e1.toString());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(this, "Benvenuto " + nome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputStream is;
            if (username.getText().length() == 0) {
                username.setText("Enter Username");
            } else if (password.getText().length() == 0) {
                password.setText("Enter Password");
            } else if (email.getText().length() == 0) {
                email.setText("Enter email");
            } else {
                try {
                    String a = username.getText().toString().trim();
                    String b = password.getText().toString().trim();
                    String c = email.getText().toString().trim();
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://tripleleon.altervista.org/register.php");
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> dati = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idutente", a));
                    dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", b));
                    dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", c));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dati,
                            HTTP.UTF_8));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                    email.setText("");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag",
                            "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

    @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle b){
        startActivity(main);
    }
}
```

P.S.: I'm italian so don't panic if you read something you don't get xD

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Do not call toast.show() if the name property == null. But I imagine you have a structural issue. Can't offer more detailed assistance without code details.

Comment: @StanSmith that's a property I've set in some other activities, where the temporal order isn't that much important. But in this case it won't work cause the toast show right after the app starts; so if it's null it won't show up in all of the cases, either if it's at the start or after the login...

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `Toast.make(...).show()` into your `onClick` handler.

As a side note, avoid using hard-coded strings in your app. Use android's resource mechanism (res/values/strings.xml) - it will make changing your app's outputs or localizing it to a different language that much easier.